# Authorizing for Google Drive and Google Sheets API together

Tags: google-drive-api, google-authentication, google-sheets-api, google-drive-realtime-api

So I'm trying to use Google Drive to get a list of file ID's and then use those file ID's to update the spreadsheets through the Google Sheets API.

I'm struggling to comprehend how exactly I should combine those authentications in Node.js in order to meet both authentications needs.

My goal is to create an Alexa app that updates spreadsheets and I currently have running and trying to expand off this app: https://github.com/acucciniello/alexa-open-doc

Because It's Alexa I'm assuming I can't store anything on the file system like I can locally so hence why I'm trying to use the token as hardcoded that I generated through my command line

Here's my attempt to combine Google Drive API + Sheets auth:

```
// authorize.js
var GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library')

// Purpose: To set the credentials from the client_secret.json and     checks if the token is valid
// param(in): credentials: Authentication information of user from     client_secret.json
// param(in):       token: The access token received from the lambda     request and google
// param(in):    callback: A function that handles the error or returns     the authentication information
module.exports = function authorize (credentials, token, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.web.client_secret
  var clientId = credentials.web.client_id
  var redirectUrl = credentials.web.redirect_uris[0]
  var auth = new GoogleAuth()
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl)
  // Check if we have previously stored a token
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: token,
  })
  oauth2Client.credentials = "MY_COMMAND_LINE_TOKEN";
  if (token === undefined) {
    var undefinedToken = 'Token is undefined, please link the skill'
    return callback(undefinedToken)
  }
  return callback(null, oauth2Client)
}
```

Here's my currently working Alexa + Google Drive Auth:

```
// authorize.js
var GoogleAuth = require('google-auth-library')

// Purpose: To set the credentials from the client_secret.json and checks if the token is valid
// param(in): credentials: Authentication information of user from client_secret.json
// param(in):       token: The access token received from the lambda request and google
// param(in):    callback: A function that handles the error or returns the authentication information
module.exports = function authorize (credentials, token, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.web.client_secret
  var clientId = credentials.web.client_id
  var redirectUrl = credentials.web.redirect_uris[0]
  var auth = new GoogleAuth()
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl)
  // Check if we have previously stored a token
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: token
  })
  if (token === undefined) {
    var undefinedToken = 'Token is undefined, please link the skill'
    return callback(undefinedToken)
  }
  return callback(null, oauth2Client)
}
```

And my Google Sheets Auth:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'sheets.googleapis.com-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Google Sheets API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the scopes. You can use any array of scopes including Drive and Sheets in the same call to authorize. Look in your client_secret.json and adjust the scopes there.

Answer (score 0):

Give both the scopes separated by a white-space:

```
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets' https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive];
```

Comment: Are you sure about that *white-space*? Wouldn't that trigger a syntax error?

Comment: No. That's how we add multiple scopes in G sheets. ['scope1' 'scope2']